# MySQL JDBC connector string truncation

Tags: java, mysql

When accessing MySQL through JDBC, the following exception was thrown from the jdbc connector (5.1.39).

> Value '\u000248$2ef8cd3c-e4d7-4ad5-8d60-504f6e7db07a\u00132016-11-21
>   17:26:37\u00132016-11-21
>   17:26:37\u0010ABCDEFGH\n2016-08-01\n2016-08-16\u0007SOMETHING\u00012\u00041481\u00011\u00042016\b50016387\u000b01026940427\u0012company
>   XYZ???\u00012$17b9f783-a7c2-4d49-bbc1-8ad73479a0b6\u00132016-11-13
>   13:31:26\u00132016-11-21
>   17:44:00\u00011\u00041481\u001bXXXXXXXXXXX\u000bcompanya\u000b00662850544\u000eabcd@email.com\bregular\u000248$57eff2d9-35e0-415a-81e4-04797192133f\u00132016-11-13
>   13:35:35\u00132016-11-22
>   14:40:03\u00072361.93\u000248\u0003EUR\u00011\bSTATUS?\n2016-12-31\n2017-03-09?\u00011\u000283\u00185828d21111000070071715f2\u000248\u000b0.001937241\u000b0.037620570\u000b0.120000000\u000b0.052392000\u000b1.000000000\u00010\u00010\u00010\u00010\u00010\u000b0.037620570\u000b0.001414463\u000b0.004799110\u00011\u00012\u00011\u000248\u000e348.743925612\f19.186074388\u000b0.012392000\u000b0.001574005\u000b0.004008749\u00010\u0000\u00130000-00-00
>   00:00:00\u00130000-00-00
>   00:00:00\u00010\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000'
>   can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp

This looks like the JDBC driver cannot correctly determine the end of strings in the result row. Our table are in latin1.

Is there anything that should be done on the connection level to prevents these issues?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved upgrading from 5.7.11 a 5.7.26. Lesson learned: do not underestimate the importance of minor releases